# AWS SecretsManagerClient using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I think I'm just missing something obvious but after struggling for pretty much the whole day yesterday with no results, I figured it was time to ask a question on here.

I'm trying to use AWS SecretsManager to store secrets for my Apache2 PHP server running on EC2. I'm using composer to load the AWS SDK for PHP, but whenever I try to create a SecretsManagerClient I get an error saying that class does not exist - I'm getting this error on my local testing server as well as when I run the code on a live server. I'm loading other libraries through composer so I think that's set up properly.

I simplified my cone down to a single file that just tries to create a new SecretsManagerClient:

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../_global/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\SecretsManager\SecretsManagerClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$client = new SecretsManagerClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => $_SERVER['AWS_REGION']
]);

exit();
```

But when I load the file in my browser I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Aws\SecretsManager\SecretsManagerClient" not found in .../aws.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in .../aws.php on line 11
```

I feel like I'm going crazy, please send help lol